# How to return enum description instead of name in API via Dto file in C#?

Tags: c#, api, enums

I have an Enum called FeeNameEnum where the FeeName also consists of Description as well. So, I am trying to return FeeName description of FeeName in my API.
Here is the enum:

```
public enum FeeNameEnum
{
        [Description("Account Opening Fee (project proponent, General Account holder, Retail Aggregation Account and End User Accoun")]
        AccountOpeningFee,
}
```

Currently, I am getting `AccountOpeningFee` which is the enum name in the api response. Is there any way I can get the Description instead of the enum name?

Here is my Dto file code:

```
public class FeeScheduleDto
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public FeeNameEnum FeeName { get; set; }
        public string FeeNameName { get { return FeeName.ToString(); } }
}
```

Any help would be more than appreciable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`DescriptionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute?view=net-7.0), from [`System.ComponentModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel?view=net-7.0), to query attributes of an enum value.
In the code below `GetEnumDescription` demonstrates the usage of `DescriptionAttribute`. It can be used to get the description of any enum value. It also falls back to the enum value itself in case a description is not available.

**Code example:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
    {
        if (value == null) { return ""; }

        DescriptionAttribute attribute = value.GetType()
                .GetField(value.ToString())
                ?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                .SingleOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;
        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
    }

    public enum FeeNameEnum
    {
        [Description("Account Opening Fee description (...)")]
        AccountOpeningFee,
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        FeeNameEnum e = FeeNameEnum.AccountOpeningFee;
        Console.WriteLine(GetEnumDescription(e));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Account Opening Fee description (...)
```

**Usage in your code:**

In your actual code you can add `GetEnumDescription` (and `using System.ComponentModel;`), then change the `FeeNameName` property from:

```
public string FeeNameName { get { return FeeName.ToString(); } }
```

To:

```
public string FeeNameName { get { return GetEnumDescription(FeeName); } }
```

In case you encounter errors, you can use this version of `GetEnumDescription` which is doing it step by step and so might help to identify where the problem comes from:

```
public static string GetEnumDescription1(Enum value)
{
    if (value == null) { return ""; }

    var type = value.GetType();
    var field = type.GetField(value.ToString());
    var custAttr = field?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    DescriptionAttribute attribute = custAttr?.SingleOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;
    return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
}
```

**Note:** the argument passed to the `value` parameter above is expected to be either a simple valid enum value, or a flag composite - "or" (`|`) of several values.

Comment: thank you for your reply. So, would I be able to use the GetEnumDescription method directly in my Dto file?

Comment: I believe so. Please see my asnwer update.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it is throwing an error as shown here - https://prnt.sc/zNbf0tjBiWqZ

Comment: Can you try my reduced standalone code example above ? Also please post you complete enum.

Comment: I also modified the implementation of `GetEnumDescription` (see above). It might make it easier to understand which stage causes the exception.

Comment: `.GetField(value.ToString())` could return `null` if `value` does not happen to be a defined value of the enum (e.g. a composite of flag values, or a default value where the enum doesn't happen to have a defined value for `0`), in which case you will get a null reference exception for `.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)`.  Maybe change to `?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)` ?

Comment: @dbc not sure I fully understand. Assuming `value` is a valid enum value - could `.GetField(value.ToString())` return `null`  ? Because that was my assumption about the usage by the OP. And that's also what I tested in my example.

Comment: My point is that `value` might not be a valid enum value -- or a flag composite value.  In such cases `ToString()` either returns a numeric string, or a comma-separated value `Flag1 | Flag2`, but your extension method will throw a null reference exception, which is what https://prnt.sc/zNbf0tjBiWqZ is showing.

Comment: @dbc I updated my answer. Tested that now it works well for a flag composite (and simple null input).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System.ComponentModel namespace to access the DescriptionAttribute class and get the description for the FeeName enum value. Here's an example:

```
public class FeeScheduleDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public FeeNameEnum FeeName { get; set; }

    public string FeeNameDescription
    {
        get
        {
            var type = typeof(FeeNameEnum);
            var member = type.GetMember(FeeName.ToString());
            var attributes = member[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            return ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
        }
    }
}
```